# Using Paperclip without rails

Tags: ruby, paperclip

Am I able to use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) in a straight ruby script run from commandline, without rails etc?

I need the Paperclip::Geometry functionality in a small ruby script I am trying to write, but it seems it needs a lot of dependencies that are a part of RoR. Is it possible to use Paperclip::Geometry without rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it w/o Rails (f.ex in some commandline ruby scripts, in Sinatra, etc), but you must have some Rails parts installed on your system.
At least following ones, with their dependencies too:

```
#gem dependency paperclip
Gem paperclip-2.4.5
  activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
  activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include Paperclip::Glue in your model,

```
class ModuleName < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Paperclip::Glue
  ...
end
```